# Not null but still getting "Field 'date' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a `date_field` form on Rails 5.2.1 + MySQL 5.7.23 and I get an error saying "Field 'date' doesn't have a default value".
I've done some googling and I understand that we get this error on MySQL 5.6+ whenever we try to insert null to a column without default value.
However, in my case, I'm selecting a date which makes it not null and I'm still getting the same error.

my new.erb:

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>CONTENT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.date_field :date %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :content %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(user_id: current_user.id, date: params[:date], content: params[:content])
    @post.save
    redirect_to('/')
  end

end
```

my MySQL settings:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What can I do to fix this? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` MySQL mode. From [MySQL 5.7 Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in
>   data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be
>   invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data
>   type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing
>   when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL
>   column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a
>   NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode
>   also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE.
>
> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for
>   invalid or missing values and produces warnings (see Section
>   13.7.5.40, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”). In strict mode, you can produce this behavior by using INSERT IGNORE or UPDATE IGNORE.
>
> For statements such as SELECT that do not change data, invalid values
>   generate a warning in strict mode, not an error.

To check whether `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode is enabled, run the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

To disable strict mode, call the following query, once you make the database connection (in your application code):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
```

OR

```
SET sql_mode='';
```

`GLOBAL` keyword requires super user privileges, and it will ensure that change is applied to all the clients connecting to server. However, **note** that the `SET GLOBAL` method will not make the changes permanent. It will only work until the MySQL Server has not been restarted. To make changes permanent, you will have to make changed in **mysqld** config files. In older MySQL versions, in Linux server(s) (for eg: Ubuntu), there is a single config file `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`, in which you add these changes below the `[mysqld]` subsection.

In newer versions, for eg, in Ubuntu server, file will be: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Although, you should really set Default values for your table columns. In case of these date fields, you can set default value to `null`:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NUL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```